# Converting a TIFF Image saved with a transparency can't be converted to JPEG image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, tiff

I am trying to solve a problem in Python where I am needing to convert TIFF images to JPEGs.  I have tried using Pillow as well as OpenCV to do this but keep getting errors when I try to convert a TIFF image that has the transparency saved on it.  If I save the TIFF and remove the transparency it saves the JPEG successfully.  The transparency has to remain on the TIFF.  Does anyone know of a solution for this issue?  If I could find a way to even save the TIFF without the transparency via a Python script, save as a JPEG, and then delete the TIFF without the transparency that would work too.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.  Below are examples of code I have tried that have failed:

```
import os
from PIL import Image

os.chdir('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/')
# for root, dirs, files in os.walk('S:/DAM/Test/Approved'):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:

        if name.endswith('.tif'):

            filename = os.path.join(root, name)
            print('These are the files: ', filename)
            # img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
            img = Image.open(filename)
            print('image is open', filename)
            img = img.convert('RGB')
            print('image should be converted: ', filename)
            imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500))
            print('image should be resized: ', filename)
            imageResize.save(filename[:-4]+'.jpg', 'JPEG')
            print('image should be saved as a jpeg: ', filename)
```

Here is the error I get when Python tries to open the TIFF with transparency using Pillow:

```
Exception has occurred: UnidentifiedImageError
cannot identify image file '.\\Beauty Images\\XXX.tif'
  File "U:\Python files\image_conversion2.py", line 22, in <module>
    img = Image.open(filename)
```

When I run this code using OpenCV it fails on the same image as well:

```
img = cv2.imread('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/XXX.tif')
cv2.imwrite('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/XXX.jpg', img)
```

Here is the error I get with this code:

```
OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:715: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
  File "U:\Python files\img_convert_new.py", line 19, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/XXX.tif', img)
```

Comment: Try using ImageMagick and running "identify -verbose XXX.tif" or share this image.
See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22170601/13226440

Comment: @Alex Alex, what will ImageMagick do for this issue?

Comment: ImageMagick will give out information about the image. In particular, about the alpha channel. A further solution to this problem depends on this information.

Comment: @Alex Alex, I don't have ImageMagick installed.  Is there another way to get this information without ImageMagick?

Comment: @Alex Alex, when I do this to get the alpha channel information in OpenCV it gives me the 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' on the image.  When I try it on an image that doesn't have an alpha channel I get the information printed.

Comment: JPG does not support transparency. If you save it with ImageMagick, you will likely get black where it was transparent. Can you post a link to your TIFF file? Might it be corrupt or in some format that OpenCV does not support such as 32-bits per channel?

Comment: Is your TIFF multi-layer or multi-page? If so, you likely need a different reader (cv2.imreadmulti)

Comment: @fmw42, It has 1 transparent layer and 5 Channels: CMYK, Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, Black

Comment: Perhaps OpenCV/PIL cannot read CMYKA images. I do not know the full limitations. ImageMagick and Python Wand can read them, but you would have to install ImageMagick. If you are on Linux, then it is already installed. OpenCV/PIL have read it, then you can make a copy and remove the alpha channel and then save from the copy, if you need to keep tha alpha channel in your original TIFF. Removing the alpha channel in OpenCV/PIL will not change the disk file. It only changes the in-memory version that was read. Can you post a link to your TIFF file?

Comment: @fmw42 how can I paste the image here for you to see?

Comment: @fmw42 I got the images to convert to jpegs using scikit-image however when they are saved they are saved as black and white images instead of color.  How do I get them to be color and then I think I will be in business?

Comment: You can upload your image to any free hosting service that will not change your image and put the URL here (see dropbox for example, but there are many others).  You probably should zip the file, because many service will not allow TIFF files.

Comment: @fmw42 I installed ImageMagick.  How do I use it in my Python script to make it do what I need?  I can't find documentation or code to do this.

Comment: Install Python Wand. It uses ImageMagick. I can then help with code.

Comment: I installed Python Wand by doing pip install Wand is that correct?

Comment: Try [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) to convert a CMYKA TIFF to a RGB JPEG: `from imagecodecs import imread, imwrite;imwrite('rgb.jpg', imread('cmyka.tif')[:,:,:3].copy())`.

Comment: @cgohlke this worked!!  Can you explain what these lines of code are doing? Also, how do I control the size and color mode of the jpeg if I need it to be 2500 x 2500 with an RGB color mode?

Comment: `imread('cmyka.tif')` returns a three dimensional numpy array. The last dimension contains the RGBA samples. `[:,:,:3].copy()` discards the alpha channel and makes a contiguous copy. Resize the numpy array with (for example) [`ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) before saving. As for JPEG compression options, see https://github.com/cgohlke/imagecodecs/blob/v2020.5.30/imagecodecs/_jpeg8.pyx#L116

Comment: @cgohlke is there anyway you can provide me with revised code to make this work to resize and make it an RGB jpeg?  I'm new to Python so not sure exactly how to write this.  Also, If i'm iterating through folders to do this for all TIFF files how would the full code look for that?

```
from imagecodecs import imread, imwrite
imwrite('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/BAR076W-BZM-C.jpg', imread('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/BAR076W-BZM-C.tif')[:,:,:3].copy())
```

Comment: @cgohlke is there anyway you can provide me with revised code to make this work to resize and make it an RGB jpeg? I'm new to Python so not sure exactly how to write this. Also, If i'm iterating through folders to do this for all TIFF files how would the full code look for that? ``` from imagecodecs import imread, imwrite imwrite('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/BAR076W-BZM-C.jpg', imread('S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/BAR076W-BZM-C.tif')[:,:,:3].copy()) ```

Comment: Thanks @cgohlke!  I was able to get it to work!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @cgohlke the solution was found!  The solution is as follows using imagecodecs.  The fullpath variable is the root + '/' + file of the source path.

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(src):
   for file in files:
      fullpath = (root + '/' + file)
```

```
from imagecodecs import imread, imwrite
from PIL import Image

imwrite(fullpath[:-4] + '.jpg', imread(fullpath)[:,:,:3].copy()) # <-- using the imagecodecs library function of imread, make a copy in memory of the TIFF File.
                    # The :3 on the end of the numpy array is stripping the alpha channel from the TIFF file if it has one so it can be easily converted to a JPEG file.
                    # Once the copy is made the imwrite function is creating a JPEG file from the TIFF file.
                    # The [:-4] is stripping off the .tif extension from the file and the + '.jpg' is adding the .jpg extension to the newly created JPEG file.
                    img = Image.open(fullpath[:-4] + '.jpg') # <-- Using the Image.open function from the Pillow library, we are getting the newly created JPEG file and opening it.
                    img = img.convert('RGB') # <-- Using the convert function we are making sure to convert the JPEG file to RGB color mode.
                    imageResize = img.resize((2500, 2500)) # <-- Using the resize function we are resizing the JPEG to 2500 x 2500
                    imageResize.save(fullpath[:-4] + '.jpg') # <-- Using the save function, we are saving the newly sized JPEG file over the original JPEG file initially created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to read a CMYKA TIFF with Python Wand, remove the alpha channel, save it to JPG and also convert the image to OpenCV format.

Input:

[image]

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
import numpy as np
import cv2

with Image(filename='guinea_pig.tiff') as img:
    display(img)

    with img.clone() as img_copy:
        # remove alpha channel and save as JPG
        img_copy.alpha_channel='off'
        img_copy.format = 'jpeg'
        img_copy.save(filename='guinea_pig.jpg')
        display(img_copy)

        # convert to opencv/numpy array format and reverse channels from RGB to BGR for opencv
        img_copy.transform_colorspace('srgb')
        img_opencv = np.array(img_copy)
        img_opencv = cv2.cvtColor(img_opencv, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # display result with opencv
        cv2.imshow("img_opencv", img_opencv)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Resulting JPG:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @fmw42!  I'll try this.  I do have one question, if my image is in this directory: S:/DAM/Test/Approved/Beauty Images/BAR076W-FB-SP.tif do I put that whole path in the filename variable or just the filename only?  The python script is running from a different location than the images..

Comment: The whole path to the tiff file, if you are running the script from some other directory.

Comment: how would the code be revised to resize the jpeg to 2500 x 2500 and make it a RGB jpeg?

Comment: Thanks @fmw42.  How would I revise the code so that it doesn't show the image but saves the jpeg in the same folder as the TIFF that it was converted from and resize it to be 2500 x 2500?

Comment: Do you need the OpenCV image that I was converted from the Wand image? If not, then I can do all that in Wand. Are you running the script from the same directory where you have the TIFF or from a different location?

Comment: I tried running this code but get this error:

Exception has occurred: ImportError
MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows
  File "U:\Python files\image_magick.py", line 18, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image

What do I need to do?  I followed the instructions on installing and linking Wand to the Environment variables.

Comment: I need the original TIFF and the jpeg that was converted.  However I get the error in my previous comment that won't allow me to use MagickWand.  What do I need to do?  I installed everything like it said to do on the download instructions page.

Comment: You need to install ImageMagick on your platform? Or put the path to ImageMagick in your $PATH environment variable if you already have it installed. What is your OS?

Comment: I installed ImageMagick yesterday and today followed the instructions on this page:  http://docs.wand-py.org/en/latest/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-windows  to set the MAGICK_HOME environment variable to the path of ImageMagick in my environment variables but I'm still getting this error.  I'm on Windows 10 OS.  What else do I need to do?  I installed this version:  ImageMagick-7.0.10-19-Q16-HDRI-x64-dll.exe. I did all of this and restarted the computer and ran the script again but am still getting the same error. I am running 32 bit Python 3.8.3.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: Did you have ImageMagick installed before installing Python Wand? I likely cannot help much, since I do not use Windows. Are you on 32-bit Windows or 64-bit Windows. If the latter, you may have to install a compatible version of Python. But again I am not an expert on Windows installs of software.

Comment: I did install ImageMagick before installing Python Wand.  I am on a 64-bit Windows.  Will having 32-bit Python not work?  I would really like to use ImageMagick but don't know what else to do.  Do I have the right version of ImageMagick installed or do I need to install a different version?

Comment: I do not know much about Windows. I will forward your issue to the Python Wand developer. He most likely can help further.

Comment: @CodeMan99 Both Python & ImageMagick must be the same x86-64 architecture. It sounds like a 32-bit python is trying to open a 64-bit dll.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 and @emcconville!  I was able to find another solution besides ImageMagick.  I wish I could have gotten it to work.  It looks like a great tool!